# Creating only month and year column in MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql

I'm creating a little program with Java. In the date field which is a `ComboBox` for selecting only month and date as `02/2016`.

Is there a way to record this date format in MySQL in a `mm/yy` field only?

Comment: At the very least, store it in yyyymm format.

Comment: @Strawberry Actually, [YYYY-MM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates) is [the standard format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of storing it in this format, maybe the best approach is to store it as a normal date with the day always set to the first day of the month. 
And then at retrieval time you format the date, with something like a SimpleDateFormat, to only get the month and year and return it to your UI.

Comment: You're right,and that what i did for them but,the th real problem is that at the end of every month,sub offices send data in paper format in the headquarter because there is no database in the sub offices.And that data wich must bé stored in the data base resumes the financial state of the office with as send the paper form.So in the existing database,for those kind of informations,only the concerned month and year is required,and not they.

Comment: You don't have to ask for the day in your UI. Ask only for the month and year as you currently do. But when you receive the information in the backend, add the day (end of the month for example) before storing it in MySql as a real date. If there are some data with only month and year information as string in the DB, it may be better to migrate them to transform them to real dates to be able to execute range and comparison operations on them and have efficient and coherent indices.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't do that, and there's no native way to do so. Just save it as a normal `DATE` in MySQL and, when you query the database `SELECT MONTH(datefield), YEAR(datefield)` or parse the date with Java.

The MySQL date and datetime types consist of a date including a day (or including a time). In order to be able to query for a *range* and other date related stuff, you should stick to the intended way of storing dates. MySQL has excellent datetime functions, you shouldn't do something that takes them away from you.

Answer (score 2):

## ISO 8601

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines many formats for strings representing date-time values. One of them is for a year and a month without any date, without a time zone, and without a time-of-day: `YYYY-MM`. Example: `2016-02` for February 2016.

## Database storage

Save these standard strings in a textual column in your database. Note that sorting alphabetically also means chronological ordering.

## Java

The java.time classes use ISO 8601 standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings that represent date-time values.

The [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class represents a year-and-month values without a date. Within your app, use these objects rather than mere strings or numbers. Doing so provides type-safety, ensures valid values, and makes your code more self-documenting.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of( 2016 , 2 );
String output = ym.toString();  // 2016-02
```

And going the other direction, parsing a standard string.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse( "2016-02" );
```

## Queries

You can perform textual queries as the standard formats are chronological when sorted alphabetically. The people on that ISO committee are so clever.

For example, to query for values in the first quarter of the year 2016:

```sql
WHERE expiration >= '2016-01' 
AND expiration <= '2016-03'
```

Also, in date-time work we usually use *Half-Open* approach to spans of time where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

```
WHERE expiration >= '2016-01' 
AND expiration < '2016-04'  // Up to, but not including, the month at end of this span.
```

Of course, you really should be using `PreparedStatement` rather than raw SQL query.

```
YearMonth q2016_ymStart = YearMonth.of( 2016 , 1 );  // 2016-01
YearMonth q2016_ymStop = q2016_ymStart.plusMonths( 3 );  // 2016-04 for half-open quarter.
…
myPreparedStatement.setString( … , q2016_ymStart.toString() );
myPreparedStatement.setString( … , q2016_ymStop.toString() );
```

And speaking of quarters, see the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project for [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html) and [`Quarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Quarter.html) classes.

## `LocalDate`

To transform a `YearMonth` to a date, use the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class.

```
LocalDate firstOfMonth = ym.atDay( 1 );
LocalDate endOfMonth = ym.atEndOfMonth();
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

To transform a `YearMonth` into a moment on the timeline, specify a time zone for the context intended by your business scenario. Let java.time determine the first moment of the day, as the first moment is *not* always `00:00:00`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ym.atDay( 1 ).atStartOfDay( z );
```

## Database access

For database access, your JDBC 4.2 compliant driver may be able to handle these java.time types directly by calling the `PreparedStatement::setObject` and `ResultSet::getObject` methods.

If not, fall back to converting the java.time types to the old java.sql types using new methods added to those old classes. Search Stack Overflow for much more info.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: If in the database  i store it as textual column,or à string,will it be possible to have a sql request such as `select * from table_name where date between dat1 and date2` ? Because this request works with number and date format,but with a date as text column,i'm not sure that it will work

Comment: If you are concerned about only year-month, then a date is irrelevant. Also, you have the crucial issue of time zone which we have ignored so far. For any given moment, the date varies around the world by zone. Search Stack Overflow for *much* more info on that. If what you are storing is something like a credit card expiration, then this Answer suffices. For a range, such as first quarter (January-March), search for `WHERE expiration >= '2016-01' AND expiration <= '2016-03'`.

Comment: What a luxurious answer. Thank you!